# Compilation / Code Generation of External Scala DSL

Tags: scala, dsl

My understanding is that it is quite simple to create & parse an external DSL in Scala (e.g. representing rules). Is my assumption correct that the DSL can only be interpreted during runtime but does not support code generation (like ANTLR) for archiving better performance ?

EDIT: To be more precise, my question is if I could achieve this (create an external domain specific language and generate java/scala code) with built-in Scala tools/libraries (e.g. http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/combinator-parsing.html). Not writing a whole parser / code generator completely by yourself in scala. It's also clear that you can achieve this with third-party tools but you have to learn additional stuff and have additional dependencies. I'm new in the area of implementing DSLs, so I have no gutfeeling so far when to use external tools like ANTLR and what you can (with a reasonable effort) do with Scala on-board stuff.

Comment: What kind of DSL are you talking about? DSL = Domain Specific Lanugage, first thing that comes to my mind.

Comment: Since you can use ANTLR in Java, why wouldn't you be able to use it in Scala? You can call any Java API from your Scala code (it just won't be as pretty as using a dedicated Scala API).

Comment: I've edited my question to be more precise

Answer (score 0):

> Is my assumption correct that the DSL can only be interpreted during runtime but does not support code generation (like ANTLR) for archiving better performance ?

No, this is wrong. It is possible to write a compiler in Scala, after all, Scala is Turing-complete (i.e. you can write *anything*), and you don't even *need* Turing-completeness for a compiler.

Some examples of compilers written in Scala include

- the Scala compiler itself (in all its variations, Scala-JVM, Scala.js, Scala-native, Scala-virtualized, Typelevel Scala, the abandoned Scala.NET, …)
- the Dotty compiler
- Scalisp
- Scalispa
- … and many others …